# Express the given quantity as a single Logarithm $\frac{1}{5}\ln(x+2)^5+\frac{1}{2}[\ln x-\ln(x^2+3+2)^2)]$

Tags: calculus

Express the given quantity as a single Logarithm

$$\frac{1}{5}\ln(x+2)^5+\frac{1}{2}[\ln x-\ln(x^2+3x+2)^2)]$$

My answer is $\ln\dfrac{[(x+2)^5]^{\frac{1}{5}}\cdot x^2}{[(x^2+3x+2)^2]^{\frac{1}{2}}}$

What have I done wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $$\displaystyle \frac{1}{5}\ln(x+2)^5+\frac{1}{2}\left[\ln(x)-\ln(x^2+3x+2)^2\right]$$

$$\displaystyle \ln(x+2)^{\frac{5}{5}}+\ln(x)^{\frac{1}{2}}-\ln(x^2+3x+2)^{\frac{1}{2}} = \ln(x+2)+\ln (\sqrt{x})-\ln(x^2+3x+2)$$

So we get $$\displaystyle \ln\left[\frac{(x+2)\cdot \sqrt{x}}{x^2+3x+2}\right] = \ln\left[\frac{(x+2)\cdot \sqrt{x}}{(x+1)(x+2)}\right] = \ln\left[\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x+1}\right]$$

Above we have Used $$\bullet\;  n\cdot \ln(m) = \ln(m)^{n}$$ and $$\displaystyle \bullet\; \ln(m)-\ln(n) = \ln\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)$$

Comment: There's one more simplification - factor $x^2+3x+2$ and cancel.